# Adding a column to dataframe that calculates the mean across rows-getting all 'NaNs' returned

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I am trying to add a column to my data frame that calculates the average across rows of a subset of my data frame columns.  I am trying this (`Min1-Min5` are the names of the subset of columns I want the average for):

```
df_temps['MinAvg'] = df_temps[['Min1', 'Min2', 'Min3', 'Min4', 'Min5']].mean(axis=1)
```

but it returns a column called `MinAvg` with all `NaN` values.  There are no `NA` or missing data points in my data frame. 
[image: shows screenshot of column with all NANs]

*Updated:  All Min Variables were string type pulled from an API.  Therefore, I needed to change it from a string to a float with the (.astype(float)) per the feedback below!  Thanks for the help!*

Comment: it'd help if you share a sample of your data.

Comment: It seems values are not numeric, so use `df_temps['MinAvg'] = df_temps[['Min1', 'Min2', 'Min3', 'Min4', 'Min5']].astype(float).mean(axis=1)`

Comment: @jezrael thank you!  That worked the values were extracted from an API as string type so I needed the .astype(float) to actually compute the average.

Comment: @Peyman thank you I will edit it to show that the values I originally added to my dataframe were strings from an API.  So I needed the .astype(float) piece that jazrael mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is type of value are `string`s, so need convert them to `float`:

```
cols = ['Min1', 'Min2', 'Min3', 'Min4', 'Min5'] 
df_temps['MinAvg'] = df_temps[cols].astype(float).mean(axis=1)
```

Or reassign back converted columns:

```
df_temps = df_temps.astype(float)

df_temps['MinAvg'] = df_temps.mean(axis=1)
```